# What are the equilibrium solutions of this first order linear system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=4x-7y-1$$ 
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=3x+6y-12$$

one part of my notes says if the determinant gives you some number other than zero then there is only one equilibrium solution (the origin).

However another part of my notes says that the equilibrium solutions are just setting each equation to zero and solving for the variables. I think the determinant answer is the "more correct" one. Please shed some light on this. Thank you.

Comment: An equilibrium is a point such that neither the $x$ nor the $y$ coordinate is changing when the trajectory is at that point. This translates to :$(x^*, y^*)$ is an equilibrium iff  $\dot{x}|_{x^*} = 0$ and  $\dot{y}|_{y^*} = 0$. Think about what this means in words - neither the $x$ nor the $y$ coordinate is changing with time when I'm sitting at $(x^*,y^*)$, implies the trajectory remains at $(x^*,y^*)$, a steadiness of sorts. The equilibrium need not be the origin - for example, in this problem neither $\dot{x}$ nor $\dot{y}$ is zero at the origin.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 that does not make sense because the determinant of this matrix yields a number that is non-zero, so the only equilibrium solution is the origin.

Comment: I don't know what determinant of what matrix you're talking about. Perhaps you should include the description of this in the question. The spiel above is simply the definition of an equilibrium.

Comment: Determinant is non-zero, but the system of linear equations is not homogeneous. So, there is unique, but non-zero solution to it.

Comment: @Evgeny okay so do u think that using matrices & eigenvalues is the wrong way to do this problem? i should find the equilibrium points by finding what makes the RHS zero. Then use those points & a computer to sketch the phase portrait?

Comment: Using matrices and eigenvalues is the right way to do this problem. They just "work fancy" if you apply them without care. The statement that the only equilibrium point is an origin was an example of such careless use.

Comment: @Evgeny thank you but im very lost. if the matrices are the right way to do it then why dont i find the determinant (to see the equilibrium solutions)? this is suggesting to follow two things that contradict each other. the det is non zero so there is only one soln but the soln is non-homogeneous. So are the matrices really the right way to go about it?

Comment: @Evgeny are u saying finding the det is zero or non zero is careless? rather find what values make the RHS zero & find the eigenvalues to find what portrait it is?

Comment: It seems that you are confusing actual definition of equilibrium (as in @stochasticboy321 comment), excerpt from your notes (which is obviously about $x'=Ax$, check them) and the question that you are asking us. There's really no contradiction here. What you have to do here is to find point at which RHS is zero vector. Whether you find them by solving linear equations by hand or by using matrices is not important.

Comment: @Evgeny okay. Then why dont mathematicians say that instead doing all of this rigor. You had a clear and concise statement. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome :) don't blame mathematicians, they are people too, even if they use rigor to write books or texts :)